# Custom folder added under this pc not auto selected by explorer

Tags: windows-10, shell, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

I successfully added a custom folder under this pc creating a new user shell folder generating a new clsid.

I’m hardly trying to achieve what happens with the default user shell folders like music, pictures and the others.

That is, if I type win key + r and write down the path C:\Users\username\Pictures explorer opens with the pictures folder selected on the left navigation pane.

The same happens when you open a file or folder dialog and write down the path C:\Users\username\Pictures, that is Explorer somehow recognizes the written path and selects the pictures folder on the left navigation pane.

This does not happen with the custom folder added under this pc, instead the c drive is selected on the navigation pane.

I tried all the possible registry tweaks but with no success.

To be more precise I know that I can open an explorer window with the custom added folder selected on the navigation pane using a shortcut, that is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Is it possible to make so that explorer recognizes the custom folder added under this pc and acts like it does with the default folders under this pc as I explained above?

Answer (score 0):

```
explorer [/n] [/e][,/root,object][[,/select],subobject]
```

```
`None` Explorer rooted at the Desktop 

`/n` Opens a new window.

`/e` Explorer View (default if nothing else is on the command line.)  

`/root,object` Starts Explorer with object the top item (normally Desktop is the top item). Eg: `explorer /e,/root,c:\` Starts Explorer with the C drive as the only drive available.  

`/select,subobject` Selects the specified subobject.
```

Replaceable parameters are `%1` (one) which is the short file or folder name for a non LFN aware program and the long name for a LFN aware program and `%l` (L) which is the long file name.

`/IDLIST`

This is an additional parameter that means a Windows internal structure is being passed. eg:

```
Explorer.exe /e,/idlist,%I
```

The `%I` is a replacable parameter representing an IDLIST.

**Rooted Views**

To open an explorer item that starts with a special folder as the top folder use the following syntax.

Where the special folder is a sub folder of the desktop

```
explorer /e,root,::{CLSID of special folder}
```

Where the special folder is a sub folder of another special folder (usually, if not always My Computer)

```
explorer /e,root,::{CLSID of parent}/::{CLSID of special folder}
```

Where the special folder is part of the file system

```
explorer /e,root,path to folder
```

**Examples**

Note that /select is inconsistent. Sometime the / is required, sometimes it should be left out, and sometimes it doesn't matter.

Starts explorer with the Windows folder opened and selected.

```
explorer /e,select,c:\windows
```

Starts explorer with Windows the top level folder and command opened and selected.

```
explorer /e,/root,c:\windows,select,c:\windows\command
```

Starts explorer with Windows the top level folder and Tips.txt showing instead of the file listing.

```
explorer /e,/root,c:\windows,select,c:\windows\tips.txt
```

Starts explorer with My Computer the top level folder and all branches except for drives collapsed.

```
explorer /e,/root,::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}
```

Starts explorer with C:\ the top level folder.

```
explorer /e,/root,c:\
```

Starts the Dial Up Networking folder in folder view.

```
explorer.exe ::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}\::{992cffa0-f557-101a-88ec-00dd010ccc48}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not useful, as i wrote in my post i know how to start explorer to achieve what i want, i want explorer to auto select the folder as it does with default folder. And by the way, the option /root does not work on windows 10 from 1809.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with **3D Objects**?

I think this may be due to those paths being associated with system folders via **HKCU...\User Shell Folders** and those system folders having a `ParsingName` value under **HKLM...\FolderDescriptions**. My entry for **3D Objects** (which I've repupsed) didn't have a parsing name & instead had a "**ParentFolder**" value that referenced {5E6C858F-0E22-4760-9AFE-EA3317B67173} (Profile), and launching the path from **Run** shows the folder under my *UserName* folder on the **Desktop**. I tried deleting **ParentFolder** and adding a **ParsingName** to its **FolderDescription**, but doesn't seem to do the trick. But I've only restarted **Explorer**, not a full signout/signin.

Do you use **3D Objects** or did you remove/hide it? Re-purposing that would give you a **FolderDescriptions** entry to play with.

Comment: Great answer Keith, unfortunatly what you found is exactly the same first thing i found, 3D objects is the only one default user shell folder that is not selected on the left navigation pane. I registered my clsid under both user shell folders and shell folders registry keys and i played a lot in folderdescriptions registry key with no success. I'm still trying to find a pattern in the mycomputer namespace, clsid and folderdescriptions registry keys.

Comment: About 3D objects (clsid {0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}) i found that there's only one entry in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace registry key, this is different from the other default user shell folders, that is, for example, music has two clsid registered under mycomputer namespace, {1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE} and {3dfdf296-dbec-4fb4-81d1-6a3438bcf4de} and only one of the relative "targetknownfolder" value (in main clsid) has "Thispcpolicy" set to show in folderdescriptions key

Comment: This question bubbled up vai "Community". Currently, Home Version 21H1 (Build 19043.1110), `3D Objects'` Address bar displays its namespace path: `This PC\3D Objects`, just like the otehr user folders. But a custom folder added to the Desktop namespace displays its file system path.